# External Double Monitor Without Ubuntu Drivers

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an external double-foldable monitor (UPERFECT dual portable) that just comes with windows and mac drivers. I can access a single monitor of it by using HDMI, but for the 2nd monitor one seems to need drivers and then it works via USB A or USB C.

I thought this would likely use some standardized interface, but so far I was without success to make it work on ubuntu. Do I generally have any chance to get such a thing work by myself?

It does not seem to support displaylink and when typing `lsusb` it shows up as

> Bus 002 Device 007: ID 345f:9132 YC USB Video

I probably don't even have to ask, because from my attempts and my current research this seems like an impossible task. However, as I have absolutely no idea about drivers, I wanted to ask if anybody has an idea. I think some sort of portability layer is also unlikely to work for that, right?